# gedit cannot open shoes2.run

Tags: character-encoding, gedit, shoes

I've just downloaded shoes but can't get them out the box.

double clicked on shoes2.run in ubuntu intrepid and gedit opened with the following message:

```
Could not open the file /home/mark/Marks files/2…ng/Programming/shoes2.run using the Unicode (UTF-8) character coding.

Please check that you are not trying to open a binary file.
Select a different character coding from the menu and try again.
```

It offered a dropdown with 2 options and a retry button:

1. Current locale (UTF-8)
2. Western (ISO-8859-15)

Neither of them are recognized.

How do i get it running?

Comment: hang bout. have solved my own problem: installed using ubuntu's "add/remove applications" thingy and it works fine.

still stands that my comp can't recognise the character encoding of the shoes2.run file i downloaded from the shoes website. m.

Answer (score 1):

m-

I had this same problem. try sudo chmoding the file :

sudo chmod 777 shoes2.run

then try running it as a script

./shoes2.run

that should work.

I am still trying to get shoes2 in my path so I can run it easily like the previous version (which I got through apt-get) right now I have to run it as a script each time I use it.

Good Luck!